# Yoneda's Lemma and $K(G,n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, yoneda-lemma

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Using the universal coefficient theorem and the Hurewicz theorem we can prove:
$$ H^n(K(G,n),G) \cong Hom(H_n(K(G,n),G),G) \cong Hom(\pi_n(K(G,n)),G) \cong Hom(G,G)$$
Calling $u$ the element corresponding to the identity of $G$ we define:
$$\psi: [X,K(G,n)] \rightarrow H^n(X,G) \quad \psi(f) = H^n(f)(u)$$
Where $[X,K(G,n)]$ is the set of continuous map from $X$ to $K(G,n)$ modulo homotopy equivalence. My professor said that this map is a bijection. I don't understand why. Recently I came across the Yoneda's Lemma and it seems to me it could be used here to prove the statement. Unfortunately I'm not able to understand which should be the functors/the spaces.

I would be grateful if someone can explain me how to use the Yoneda's Lemma or in case I'm wrong how to prove the statement. Thank you.

Comment: The Yoneda lemma just tells you that $\psi$ can be identified with a particular cohomology class in $H^n(K(G, n), G)$, namely $u$, which you already knew; but it doesn't help you prove that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ok, which is a way to prove it is an isomorphism?

Comment: this can be found in most standard books on algebraic topology, see, for instance, Prasolov, Elements of Homology Theory, Thm 3.10 An informal and readable sketch of proof is on page 19 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.6257.pdf